# onkeyDown / onBackPressed are not working with intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onkeydown, onbackpressed

This is a simple operation and seems to be working until I've changed my minSdk = **8 to 9** , and targetSdk remains **21** in my manifest.
Problem is that i have an activity A , and i am going to activity B when a button is pressed in activity A . Now on activity B whenever someone press back button i want to clear the activity stack and transfer my activity B to activity C . but instead it finish activity B and go to Activity A , so far i have tried **onKeyDown , onBackPressed** , nothing seems to work , kindly help.

Activity A (**in onClick method**):

```
Intent in = new Intent(A.this,
                            B.class);
in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(in);
```

[**UPDATED**]Activity B :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent in = new Intent(this, C.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable("Scores", score);

    in.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivity(in);
}
```

Activity C:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.C);
    ScoreSaver scores = (ScoreSaver) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("Scores");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:noHistory="true"` to both Activity A and B in your manifest file. This way these activities won't be in your back stack.
In Activity B you have to override the behavior of `onBackPressed()`.
It has to look like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

If you leave `super.onBackPressed()` in your method, the default behavior will happen, i.e. Activity B will be closed and you jump back to Activity A.

Comment: Now my whole app is closing if i press back button on activity B

Comment: Hmm.. I'm sorry. I set up a test project and it worked :-/

Comment: can you upload your source somewhere , and give me link ? that would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with Serializable object which was using storing context which will be null in next activity , which causes exception , that crashes my activity. so i removed it everything works fine. Thanks @Chris Fox

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I do not have a Git Account, so I post the files' content here. (The app's theme inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`)

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="fox.chris.activitytest">

<application android:allowBackup="true"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
             android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".ActivityA"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityB"
        android:noHistory="true">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ActivityC">

    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Activity A:

```
public class ActivityA extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
public class ActivityB extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Activity C:

```
public class ActivityC extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_c);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not including serializable object transfer lines of code ,  i have also included that , it mean that lines are causing this issue ? , what can it be ?